# KotlinExtensions.kt line XX retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$await$2$2.onResponse got this countless time with Crashlytics

Tags: android, kotlin, network-programming, crashlytics

I'm developing an app recording with a background service your position and sending it to a server, every second. As many other users, we have to deal with battery saver to make sure the background service works properly. And we have to thanks daily dontkillmyapp.co/ for their outstanding work.

However, I got a issue reported with `Crashlytics` countless time

`KotlinExtensions.kt line 53 retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$await$2$2.onResponse`

This error is reported as non fatal, but usually it match with the exact time the background service is being killed by the system, silently.

Our app is being generally used with poor network conditions. Still, is it normal to have such reports? Or definitively this error should not be triggered by `Crashlytics` if the app was handling well his network latencies or reliability?

Thanks

Comment: Is it related ? https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3474

Comment: Sadly, no @LongRanger

Comment: @Toucouleur, have you found a solution for this error?

Comment: @Toucouleur Do you have a fix for this issue?

Comment: No, this issue remains open

Comment: I have this problem too. Is there a github issue I can vote for?

Comment: If you're using okhttp3.Authenticator for your okHttp client, check if everything works right there.

Answer (score 1):

The 'await' method may be what causing it, when trying to sync API calls. These calls are somewhat problematic when they are ivoked by a background service and when sent frequenly.
Instead of using 'await' best to use async calls. (enqueue or callback).
See: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/returning-data-from-asynchronous-api-call-in-kotlin/20039

Comment: not really a canonical answer but thanks for the try